# Are "What is State of the Art for Machine Learning in X" on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I often need to discern what the State of the Art (SOTA) is for certain Machine Learning Applications, which I currently ask on the Fast.ai forums. For example:

- [How does Deep Learning deal with missing values in time series?](https://forums.fast.ai/t/missing-values-in-time-series-data/28155?u=seanny123)
- ["Explanability" analysis for time-series regression in Deep Learning](https://forums.fast.ai/t/explanability-of-rnns/31598?u=seanny123)

I don't think these are on-topic, because the question essentially boils down to "what's out there?" which isn't very answerable and seems more suitable for a forum and/or wiki. However, I wanted to check my conclusion with the community before self-filtering.

Comment: I'm afraid that with "what's deep learning SOTA for X" we would have to update the answers every week...

Comment: Somewhat related is: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5540/chaos-theory-thread-reopening-request-with-a-detailed-answer-ready  I believe that is very important for such questions to describe a clear scope, and this is a bit of a grey area. What is expected to be a sufficient answer? A question that is phrased as 'how does X deal with Y?' is already more specific than 'what are (latest) examples of X dealing with Y' (how big of a list is expected, does it need to be exhaustive, just provide a few of the most recent/important, how novel does it need to be to classify as sota, etc?)

Comment: No one objected to my question about SOTA for some image benchmarks https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363640/what-are-the-current-state-of-the-art-convolutional-neural-networks/363641#363641

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both of those examples seem to me to be well researched, & narrow enough in scope for our Q&A site. "What's state-of-the-art in supervised learning", on the other hand, would, I think, be too broad.

Comment: In other words, specific problems presented with sufficient context can be considered on-topic? I'm just trying to rephrase this to make sure I understand.

Comment: @Seanny123: Yes. The 2nd example could perhaps do with some clarification: what kind of explanation are you looking for? - global or local?